# find Mount point from cat /etc/fstab with ansible

Tags: python, linux, ansible

i would create a playbook that Check `Mount_points` for `fstype:ext` related to the `vars: whitelist` so it will iterate through the vars to check if mount_point exists or not if it exists an output should be similar to this, else it will be ignored

`/ /boot /home /opt /var /var/opt /var/tmp /var/log /var/log/audit` 
here is my playbook which was using 'xfs' as i don't have ext in my machine.
Could you advise about more efficient way to achieve the desired result

```
  - hosts: all
    vars:
      whitelist:
        - '/'
        - '/boot'
        - '/home'
        - '/opt'
        - '/var'
        - '/bin'
        - '/usr'  

    tasks:
      - set_fact:
          mount_point: "{{ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('fstype', 'match', '^xf+') | map(attribute='mount')}}"
      - debug:
          var: mount_point

        loop: "{{ whitelist }}"
        when: item in mount_point
```

```
TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible2]
ok: [ansible3]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible2] => (item=/) => {
    "msg": [
        "/",
        "/boot"
    ]
}
ok: [ansible2] => (item=/boot) => {
    "msg": [
        "/",
        "/boot"
    ]
}
skipping: [ansible2] => (item=/home)
skipping: [ansible2] => (item=/opt)
skipping: [ansible2] => (item=/var)
skipping: [ansible2] => (item=/bin)
skipping: [ansible2] => (item=/usr)
ok: [ansible3] => (item=/) => {
    "msg": [
        "/boot",
        "/"
    ]
}
ok: [ansible3] => (item=/boot) => {
    "msg": [
        "/boot",
        "/"
    ]
}
skipping: [ansible3] => (item=/home)
skipping: [ansible3] => (item=/opt)
skipping: [ansible3] => (item=/var)
skipping: [ansible3] => (item=/bin)
skipping: [ansible3] => (item=/usr)

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
ansible2                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
ansible3                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Do you want all mounts that use an ext2/3/4 filesystem? Or do you really want all mounts that have `ext` anywhere in their device path, in their mount point, or their mount options and in any possible trailing comments?

Comment: Tangentially, you want to avoid the (double) [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep). In brief, anything which looks like `grep x | grep -v y | awk '{ print z }'` can be refactored to `awk '/x/ && !/y/ { print z }'`

Comment: @Thomas i want all mounts tha have ext anywhere in their device path as i will loop with "bin" "boot" "etc" "lib" "lib64" "opt" "sbin" "srv" "usr" "var" "home"
it will do this
``` #check if fs is to include
        for item in ${WHITELIST[*]} do [[ -z "${FS_TO_ADD}" ]] && { FS_TO_ADD="$(echo "$i" | grep -e "^/${item}")" ; }  done
        [[ ! -z "${FS_TO_ADD}" ]] && { FS_TSM+=( "${FS_TO_ADD}" ) ; }
        FS_TO_ADD="" ```
so i will define those variables in the beginning
```WHITELIST=( "bin" "boot" "etc" "lib" "lib64" "opt" "sbin" "srv" "usr" "var" "home" )
FS_TSM=( "/" ) 
```

Comment: That's a different question. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

This hopefully does what you need:

```
    - name: List all mount points on which an ext2/ext3/ext4 file system is mounted
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('fstype', 'in', ['ext2', 'ext3', 'ext4']) | map(attribute='mount')}}"
```

First it uses `selectattr` to keep only those mounts whose `fstype` is one of `ext2`, `ext3` or `ext4`. Then it uses `map` to extract the mount point from each entry. The result is a list, for example `["/", "/usr", "/var"]`.